# How prevalent is animal sacrifice in India as part of Hindu ritual?

Tags: animals, sacrifice

I was under the impression that animal sacrifice as Hindu ritual was a minority phenomenon in India.

Am I wrong? Are there any statistics available?

Note that I am not asking if it is justified, that has already been answered many times before.

Comment: It used to be widespread but then after the advent of Buddhism and Jainism, Yagnas became less common, and after the time of Madhvacharya some people started using pishta-pasus or cornflour animals instead of actual animal sacrifice.  Nowadays animal sacrifice in Vedic Yagnas is pretty much non-existent.  But there is still a small amount of non-Vedic animal sacrifice done by Hindus, for instance in some temples of Kali and similar goddesses.

Comment: @Keshav can you write an answer in more detail?